# Magento2 product edit error

Tags: magento2, product

> Notice: Undefined offset: 90 in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/ResourceModel/ReadHandler.php
>   on line 167

Above error I'm getting. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

It's luck of information for the issue, but it looks like custom attribute with id = 90 has been created, but cannot be found. Try to clean cache and rebuild indexes